# Rendering Radar Chart with data received by rest call

Tags: extjs4, radar-chart

I have a radar chart which renders when read from json file. i have used listeners for this purpose. Now, I need this to be upgraded to rest call. I have a rest call which is fired when I click a button. This rest call returns data to a store and data model. I want to render the radar chart using this data. So each time the button is clicked, a new set of data is returned. How can I achieve the rendering of the radar chart each time new data is received?

If any code is needed, please feel free to ask for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Charts get automatically redrawn when their stores are updated. Make sure you use the same store instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rendering a mock chart initially using listeners. On button click I use a different set of data model, store and listeners (within the button's handler function). This store fires the rest call and loads the new chart each time the button is clicked.